# VBA Logic Row Titles to Columns Excel

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, logic

I'm having trouble with the logic of some VBA code and because of this I can't really provide any code because it's missing too many parts.. Basically what I need to do is change something from this:

```
A
x1
x2
x3
B
y1
y2
y3

Into this:
A
x1 A
x2 A
x3 A
B
y1 B
y2 B
y3 B
```

This is a large excel document so a loop would be necessary! Any guidance is of course appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also it can be assumed that each subset of the groups repeats only 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub cutaneous()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N - 3 Step 4
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value & " " & v
        Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = Cells(i + 2, 1).Value & " " & v
        Cells(i + 3, 1).Value = Cells(i + 3, 1).Value & " " & v
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I wish I had a 15 reputation so I could upvote that because it's exactly what I wanted! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if you always had exactly 3 subitems under your header. If you had two or four; this would not work. I would personally implement little different solution, maybe something like this:

```
Sub DistinguishItems()
    Dim iLastRow, iCounter As Long
        iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim sDistinguisher As String


    For iCounter = 1 To iLastRow
        If Len(Range("A" & iCounter)) = 1 Or IsNumeric(Right(Range("A" & iCounter).Value, 1)) = False Then
            sDistinguisher = Range("A" & iCounter).Value
        Else
            Range("B" & iCounter).Value = sDistinguisher
        End If
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```